# Designing left and right shift registers using D type flip flops

Tags: digital-logic

One of my digital logic textbook questions asks to rewire a parallel-in parallel-out right-shift register to make it a left-shift register. The connections made in the answer key make sense, but I'm very confused as to why `SH = 0` and `L = 1` causes a left shift.

My understanding is that if `SH = 1`, the clock input is enabled regardless of the status of `L`, and if `L = 1` the clock input is disabled if `SH = 0`. However, if `SH = 0` and `L = 1`, how can the `Q3` by serial out. Wouldn't it only output the third bit? Also if `SH = 1`   doesn't this just lead to the left shift because of the rewiring we did?

[image]
[image]

Comment: If the shift enable is 0 (no shift), but the load enable is active 1 (parallel load), then you can just see that Q2..Q0 gets loaded into D3..D1, with D0 coming from the SI input. That's a left shift if I've ever seen one. How is that complicated?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This design topology is called `bidirectional shift register`. It has 4 modes to configure output due to `S1` and `S0` pins. In your case these pins are `SH` and `LD`.

If the shift register has only `S0` select pin (or `SH` in your case), this register just capable of shifting right or left due to `SH` pin condition (If you want to check how it works, you can watch [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zoEeQgQkPLA)). Besides it can not take parallel input.

[image: image from this pdf]

---

When another select pin `S1` (in your case it is `LD`) we get 2 more options due to \$ 2^{\ number \ of \ select \ pins} = 4\$ as shown below. (You can check [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4UIIBCVU3gY) to how it works with 2 select pins)

[image]

---

> My understanding is that if `SH = 1`, the clock input is enabled regardless of the status of `L`, and if `L = 1` the clock input is disabled if `SH = 0`.

- `CLK` pin is independent from `SH` and `LD` pins.

> However, if  `SH = 0` and `L = 1`, how can the `Q3` by serial out. Wouldn't it only output the third bit?

- It can be verify from the table above. `SH` and `LD` pins just to control left/right shift or parallel load.

> Also if `SH = 1` doesn't this just lead to the left shift because of the rewiring we did?

- `SH = 0` and `LD = 1` makes the register shifts left together.